# Unable to reach a device on another net while having routes

Tags: switch, layer3

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and would therefore need some guidance. The goal is to be able to have a SSH connection between: 
PC -> C

On PC I have created a route

```
route add 192.168.50.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.2.11
```

On A I have created a static route

```
configure
ip 
route 192.168.50.0/24 vlan2
end
```

After this, I can ping `192.168.50.1` and `50.3` but not `50.2`. This is strange because pinging `50.3` can only go through `50.2` since B doesn't have any static routes.

Why can't I ping `50.2`?

I have set all IPs to static. Enabled Routing in A. Enabled IP forwarding unicast in A. Disabled default gateway on A.

[image]

Comment: My background in networking is very limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch C, as a member of the `192.168.50.0/24` subnet, requires a route back to `192.168.2.0/24` through `192.168.50.1`. There is no route required for C's switching function (nor even any IP configuration at all) but for sending a reply to outside its subnet there is.

If you use static routing, *all* hosts have to get a static route to the other subnet or a default gateway.

Switch A doesn't need a static route because `192.168.50.0/24` is locally attached to it.

Additionally, your VLAN setup is messed up. C uses VLAN ID 1 for the same segment as A's and B's VLAN ID 2. While this doesn't matter as long as you don't tag between the switches (VLAN trunking), once you activate tagging it'll break the segment.

Comment: I removed the static route on A; added a static route on C. It works. I literally jumped off my chair! Thank you!

Comment: Just keep in mind that routes need to be consistent both ways at all times.